# Frankfurt theme : sections too long to fit in a single line

Tags: beamer, header

As shown below i have many sections that wont fit in a single header line in frunk furt theme. While navigating through slides how to make the header scrolling so that the remaining section headers are also shown. please see the header[image: header with too many sections that wont appear in one line]

Comment: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: What about split document in parts? Use `\part{}` and the header should reset (I think).

Comment: Thank you  very much ,\part{} works

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was solved in the comments.